How to protect script files from being revealed by AssetRipper?
I’ve recently been learning how to prevent or secure my Unity game from being extracted. I used AssetRipper to extract someone else’s game, but it was not able to extract the code. Instead, it gave me a dummy class.
The extracted script looks like this:
  using UnityEngine;
  public class ABC : MonoBehaviour
  {

Dummy class. This could have happened for several reasons:

1. No dll files were provided to AssetRipper.

    Unity asset bundles and serialized files do not contain script information to decompile.
        * For Mono games, that information is contained in .NET dll files.
        * For Il2Cpp games, that information is contained in compiled C++ assemblies and the global metadata.
        
    AssetRipper usually expects games to conform to a normal file structure for Unity games of that platform.
    A unexpected file structure could cause AssetRipper to not find the required files.

2. Incorrect dll files were provided to AssetRipper.

    Any of the following could cause this:
        * Il2CppInterop assemblies
        * Deobfuscated assemblies
        * Older assemblies (compared to when the bundle was built)
        * Newer assemblies (compared to when the bundle was built)

    Note: Although assembly publicizing is bad, it alone cannot cause empty scripts. See: https://github.com/AssetRipper/AssetRipper/issues/653

3. Assembly Reconstruction has not been implemented.

    Asset bundles contain a small amount of information about the script content.
    This information can be used to recover the serializable fields of a script.

    See: https://github.com/AssetRipper/AssetRipper/issues/655

4. This script is unnecessary.

    If this script has no asset or script references, it can be deleted.
    Be sure to resolve any compile errors before deleting because they can hide references.

5. Script Content Level 0

    AssetRipper was set to not load any script information.

6. Cpp2IL failed to decompile Il2Cpp data

    If this happened, there will be errors in the AssetRipper.log indicating that it happened.
    This is an upstream problem, and the AssetRipper developer has very little control over it.
    Please post a GitHub issue at: https://github.com/SamboyCoding/Cpp2IL/issues

7. An incorrect path was provided to AssetRipper.

    This is characterized by "Mixed game structure has been found at" in the AssetRipper.log file.
    AssetRipper expects games to conform to a normal file structure for Unity games of that platform.
    An unexpected file structure could cause AssetRipper to not find the required files for script decompilation.
    Generally, AssetRipper expects users to provide the root folder of the game. For example:
        * Windows: the folder containing the game's .exe file
        * Mac: the .app file/folder
        * Linux: the folder containing the game's executable file
        * Android: the apk file
        * iOS: the ipa file
        * Switch: the folder containing exefs and romfs

*/
} 

Could someone help me understand how to protect my game from this kind of extraction?

What do you see in the asset ripper log? This might not be an obfuscation technique at all, but some other error that can't necessarily be counted on for long-term security.

@DMGregory Yes, this is not an obfuscation technique at all that's why I was confused, extract 2 or 3 games and check the security of the data. The tool extracts all data such as sprites, audio, etc. However, when I open any scripts, the code looks like the one I uploaded in my question, where the code writer is hidden under the main class.

I extracted my own game using this tool but did not get the same result that's why I was confused and find the way to do this @DMGregory

Nothing special on a log, just a list of exported data see on log @DMGregory
